# @JoinTable ou @JoinColumn

Tags: java, aplicação-web

Boa tarde, pessoal
Tenho um diagrama como abaixo e estou com uma dúvida. É entre Usuario e Conta e o que estou em dúvida é, se eu acessar por CONTA, eu encontro o USUÁRIO, mas não consigo ao inverso.
Minha pergunta é, está correto fazer desta forma? Como eu usuario não sei minha conta? só a conta sabe quem sou...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Poderia fazer um @JoinTable e fazer uma terceira tabela onde os dois lados teriam acesso.
Me ajudem a melhor forma. Muito obrigado!

Comment: O usuário pode ter muitas contas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O usuário pode ter n contas. Caso queira que a conta tenha acesso ao usuário e vice-versa, pode utilizar associação bidirecional.

Comment: Este diagrama foi meu professor que passou e a principio achei estranho. No caso, se for bidirecional, vou estar modificando o diagrama.

Comment: Então, outra solução seria criar outra tabela. Mas, da mesma forma estaria modificado o diagrama :D. Pra mim, faz sentido o usuário ter n contas.

Comment: Estou com problemas em salvar o lançamento, podem me ajudar?

Comment: Lançamento tem CONTA, CATEGORIA, USUARIO, mas ao adicionar ItemLancamento estou com problema, porque dá mensagem de NullPointerException. Tenho que criar ITEM e ao mesmo tempo criar lançamento... ??????????????????

Comment: Cria outra pergunta e posta o código para que seja possível identificar o motivo da exceção. Lembra de da como resolvida esta pergunta, caso tenha resolvido o lance do diagrama.